# What's this object in Comparable of Java

Tags: java, comparable

For natural ordering , I was using comparable and I found as soon as I use the method

```
  public int compareTo(T o1) {      
        System.err.println("this "+this.empID+" that "+((Employee<T>)o1).empID);
        return this.empID - ((Employee<T>)o1).empID;
    }
```

It works fine, but the this.empID is coming with some logic and that I am not able to figure out. So what is the logic behind this.empID values and what is iteration , is it like on calling sort method , internally the algo is taking care that part (sorting algorithm)

For Example :

on trying to print this.empID and that the output is

```
this 1 that 5
this 6 that 1
this 6 that 5
this 3 that 5
this 3 that 1
this 7 that 5
this 7 that 6
this 4 that 5
this 4 that 3
this 8 that 5
this 8 that 7
this 2 that 5
this 2 that 3
this 2 that 1
```

From where the value of **this** is coming , or what is the iteration logic, is it because of Sorting algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean "is coming with some logic"? `empID` looks like a simple field. Fields don't have logic, they only have values. Are you looking for the logic that *sets* that field?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Logic behind empID attribute of you class?

Comment: He is asking why the objects are being invoked in the order as displayed by his printout. I guess his *real* question is what the algorithm is for sorting a list of his objects.

Comment: yes , Is the algorithm MergeSort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about what code is calling your `compareTo` method, you're right that it will generally be called as part of a sorting algorithm. For example, if you insert an `Employee a` into a TreeSet which contains `Employee b`(say), you may see calls like `a.compareTo(b)` or `b.compareTo(a)`, depending on the exact sorting algorithm. In the first case, `this` is `a`, and in the second case `this` is `b` and `that` is `a`.

To see which code is calling `compareTo()`, you can set a breakpoint in that method and use a debugger. Alternatively, a quick and crude technique to see the stack traces of the calls is to add the following to `compareTo()`

```
Exception e = new Exception(); // This prepares a call stack
e.printStackTrace(); // This prints it
```

Obviously, this kind of debug output is very costly in performance terms, as well as verbose, so it should not be left in production code.